# Cравнение строк в двух файлах

Tags: bash

Что имееться - два файла: **1.txt** и **2.txt**

В **1.txt**:

```
val1=1
val2=2
val3=3
val4=4
```

В **2.txt**:

```
val1=11
val4=44
val5=5
val6=6
```

Каким образом на баше сравнить эти два файла построчно и все переменые из файлы **1.txt** у которых значения отличаються от **2.txt** заменить на значения из **2.txt** + добавить переменные которые остутствуют в файле **1.txt** что бы на выходе получился файл:

```
val1=11
val2=2
val3=3
val4=44
val5=5
val6=6
```

Можно на основании этих двух файлов формировать 3 файл  ***3.txt*** с соответствующими изменениями. Большое спасибо за помощь.

Comment: обязательно на bash, или perl/python есть?

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov да, нужен bash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

если имена всех ваших переменных начинаются, например, со строки "val", то можно сделать, например, так:

```
#!/bin/bash
unset ${!val@}
source 1.txt
source 2.txt
for x in ${!val@}; do
   echo "$x=${!x}"
done > 3.txt
```

вся «хитрость» — в т.н. [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

> ```
> ${!prefix*}
> ${!prefix@}
> ```
>
> Expands to the names of variables whose names begin with prefix, separated by the first character of the IFS special variable.

первая из команд — `unset` — добавлена на всякий случай. она удалит все переменные, имена которых возвращает уже упомянутая конструкция `${!val@}`: вдруг у вас в окружении затесались какие-нибудь переменные, имена которых тоже начинаются со строки "val".

Comment: спасибо - интересный способ - я попробую. И спасибо за обьяснение к коду!

Answer (score 3):

Используйте *Awk*:

```awk
BEGIN {
	FS = "=";
}

{
	a[$1] = $2;
}

END {
	for (i in a) {
		print(i "=" a[i]);
	};
}
```

```sh
$ awk -f ./tmp.awk ./1.txt ./2.txt
```

Comment: и метка — bash, и в комментарии автор вопроса подчеркнул, что решение нужно на языке bash. значит подойдёт и программа awk. логично.

Comment: @Ainar-G все получилось - огромное спасибо!

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin  Вы прекрасно знаете, что люди часто используют метку [bash], когда имеют в виду «Всё, что связано с *Shell*-скриптами».  Так что давайте без сарказма.